# Sleep(4000) Show . for each 1000 (C++)

Tags: c++

Note I am a beginner.

What I am trying to do is display a "." for each 1000 seconds in the timer. I would like the "." to be displayed next following the cout.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>


using namespace std;

int main()

{

    char uname;
    char pword;

    cout << "Initializing EKG";
    Sleep(4000);
      /* while/for Sleep(1000) cout << "."
         while Sleep(1000*2) cout << "."
      */
     //Something along those lines I am trying to achieve. 
     //Can't I use a ++ or something similar to increase the . to .. to ... to ....? 

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Sometimes I wonder whether people look at the preview while composing a question.

Comment: `Sleep` works in milliseconds, not seconds, for what it's worth.

Comment: Which platform & OS?  You may want to have a separate thread execute a function that prints a '.' every second.  This would allow your program to print '.' while performing other operations.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews `#include <windows.h>`

Answer (score 5):

You can use a simple for loop to do this.

```cpp
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
      Sleep(1000);
      cout << ".";
}
```

Comment: You can also use a while loop like this: 
int i = 0;
while(i < 4){
   Sleep(1000);
   cout << ".";
    i++;
}